# Error: "spawn dot ENOENT" when open side preview, but i've already installed Graphviz(dot)

Tags: jupyter-notebook, vscode-extensions, graphviz, vscode-debugger, dot

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JFuSx.png)
i followed a tutorial of visualizing a decision tree, i opened a DOT file in VSCODE and installed graphviz extension(by stephanvs),then opened the side preview,

it should display a picture of the decision tree, but the error"spawn dot ENOENT" appeared.

p.s. i can't find the graphviz extension by "João Pinto"

Answer (score 0):

You installed "graphviz extension", but you probably did not install Graphviz itself.
Assuming you are using Windows, in a **cmd** or **powershell** window type `dot -V`.  If you get `'dot' is not recognized ...`, that is a strong hint.
Go here: https://www.graphviz.org/download/#windows and download and install the 32-bit EXE ofor the latest version.
Then repeat the `dot -V` test.